# Произвольная навигация по view

Tags: objective-c, ios

Необходимо реализовать навигацию между view по принципу веб сайта. Пользователь может перейти с любого экрана на главную страницу приложения, на экран about, в контакты и т.п. Фактически приложение представляет набор экранов со ссылками почти на все другие экраны. Насколько я понимаю push и тем более modal тут не подходит. Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Ну сделайте переходы между окнами не через сторибоард а в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример навигации реализованной в коде "[PERFORMING SEGUES IN IOS PROGRAMMATICALLY"](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/performing-segues-in-ios-programmatically)
Кнопки можно сделать ввиде гиперссылко и вуаля.

Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Видимо это оно, только я не понимаю по какому принципу происходит создание экранов и их удаление из памяти. Руками то мы соответствующие объекты не создаем и не удаляем. Главный экран создается автоматически при запуске приложения. Но что происходит с открываемыми через segue? Например есть MainController и Controller1, Controller2. Я вручную активирую через segue MainController->Controller1->Controller2->MainController. Останутся ли объекты Controller1,Controller2 в памяти, будут уничтожены или останутся в стеке? Стек то мне вообще не нужен. P.S. Программирую под IOS третий день :)